# Detect coming back from app settings/background with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app asks permission to use location services.

If a user denies permission, they can click a button to go to the settings page and grant permissions.

On ios, they are given the option to return directly to the app. on Android, I think they can do something similar.

Is there a way to detect arriving back at the app so I can check their permissions again?

I've tried with React Navigation's [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook) hook:

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log("navigated")
        return () => getPosition()
    }, [])
)
```

But unfortunately, that only works when navigating between screens/routes in the app.

Is there a way to detect the app transitioning from background to foreground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can track app state with https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

in pseudo-code: if previously 'background' and now 'active' then run your effects

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, when I want to manage permission, I use [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions). In this way you can manage all permissions directly in your app without exit from it.

Works well for iOs and Android. In your case, you could something like:

```
import {check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';

check(<permission you need>)
  .then((result) => {
    switch (result) {
      case RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE:
        console.log(
          'This feature is not available (on this device / in this context)',
        );
        break;
      case RESULTS.DENIED:
        console.log(
          'The permission has not been requested / is denied but requestable',
        );
        break;
      case RESULTS.GRANTED:
        console.log('The permission is granted');
        break;
      case RESULTS.BLOCKED:
        console.log('The permission is denied and not requestable anymore');
        break;
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // …
  });
```

Comment: But if they select "Never" give permissions then this will always come back as BLOCKED right? Which is why I'm accounting for going to settings and back :)

Comment: Ciao, by recalling `check(<permission>)` you could ask again to the user if he want to allow permission (except if he checks "Never ask again").

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed. On ios, the only options a user gets are "Never", "While using the app" or "Always". Clicking "Never" means that it always comes back as blocked even if you `check()` or `request()` again.

Comment: Another thing: if you try to use `openSettings().catch(() => console.warn('cannot open settings'));` and then click the back button, you should return to your app. But I don't know if this is qhat you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use this hook:

```js
// hooks/useAppIsActive.ts

import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AppState } from "react-native";

export default (callback: Function) => {
  const appStateRef = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const handleAppStateChange = useCallback((nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appStateRef.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      callback();
    }

    appStateRef.current = nextAppState;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

And from the component you want to detect "the come back", pass by parameter the callback you want to run:

```js
const MyView = () => {
  const requestLocationAccess = useCallback(() => {
    // request permissions...
  }, [])

  useAppIsActive(() => requestLocationAccess());
}
```